# A group of order 30 has at most 7 subgroups of order 5

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that a group of order 30 has at most 7 subgroups of order 5.

This should be a basic question (from an introductory algebra course), but I got no clue... Please help!

Comment: Each subgroup of order 5 will contain the identity element & 4 other elements. These four elements had better be different to four other elements in a different subgroup. Now count the elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's going to have fewer than $7$, but proving that requires some tools it doesn't sound like you have.

Two distinct subgroups of order $5$ intersect only in the identity (by Lagrange's theorem). This means no two will share any nonidentity elements. Thus if there are $m$ subgroups of order $5$, you can calculate exactly how many elements are in their union. This can't be more than $30$, the order of the group.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just curious, can you tell me more about "It's going to have fewer than 7"?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems @JASON

Comment: How does the fact that distinct subgroups of order 5 follow by lagrange's theorem?

Comment: @Hristmar The intersection of two subgroups of order $5$ is a subgroup of a group of order $5$ (either one). Therefore its order divides $5$, and is smaller than $5$. The only such number is $1$.

Answer (score 9):

The intersection of two subgroups is itself a subgroup. Lagrange's Theorem therefore implies that the intersection of two subgroups of order $5$ must have order $1$ or $5$.  Therefore, two distinct subgroups of order $5$ must intersect only at the identity element.

If there are $k$ distinct subgroups of order $5$, then there are $1+4k$ distinct elements in those subgroups, which must be at most the order of the group.

---

Using this [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code

```
for G in AllSmallGroups(30) do
  S:=Set(List(G,g->Group(g)));
  Print(StructureDescription(G)," ",Number(S,H->Size(H)=5),"\n");
od;
```

We can check that every group of order $30$ actually has a unique subgroup of order $5$.  These groups are $C_5 \times S_3$, $C_3 \times D_{10}$, $D_{30}$, and $C_{30}$.  (See also [Groups of order 30](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_30).)

Answer (score 0):

Apply Sylow theorem,
$$30 = 2 \times 3 \times 5.$$ 
No. Of Sylow 5 sub-groups $= 1 \mod 5$ and divides 6, i.e. 1 or 6

So, max 6 subgroups of order 5 is possible.

Comment: Your answer is quite hard to understand.  I've edited it to include some MathJax, but it could use some additional work.  Writing in complete sentences would be a good start.